# ios8 Hide/Show Navigation Bar and Toolbar

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, toolbar

iOS 8.2 - iPad or iPhone.

I'm creating a basic Master-Detail app in Xcode to test the UISplitViewController.  I'm selecting my detail-navigation controller from the storyboard and selecting that I want to show the toolbar. This appears in the storyboard.

I'm also selecting Hide Bars on Tap in the properties window (as shown).

[image]

However, when I run the app, only my Navigation bar appears/disappears. The toolbar remains static at the bottom of the screen. Even if I set this in code, my toolbar is still static.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as UISplitViewController
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as UINavigationController
    navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()
    splitViewController.delegate = self

    navigationController.hidesBarsOnTap = true;
    return true
}
```

Yet the documentation suggests both bars should be hidden/shown on tap.

> Discussion When the value of this property is YES, the navigation
>   controller toggles the hiding and showing of its navigation bar and
>   toolbar in response to an otherwise unhandled tap in the content area.
>   The default value of this property is NO.

Does this property actually work on the toolbar? If so, is there anything else I should be doing? Thanks

Comment: have you tried hiding it with `setToobarHidden:animated:` already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The toolbar will only hide if you have put a bar button item inside.

Comment: Gah!!!!  It's so easy when you know how. Isn't it?  Thanks. Frustration over...now back to some productivity